# Updating a google spreadsheet table with an excel file

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to update a table that is shared. The info for this table is first collected into an Excel table files and then uploaded to google drive every day. I found some code that converts the .xls files to a google spreadsheet file, I need to copy the data from this converted file and update the shared one each day. My problem now is that the file I will use for updating the shared spreadsheet will be different eachday, so how can I have the script to get the new file ID eachday. I need these updates to be done automatically each day. 
This is the code I have found so far but can't seem to get it to work. First part converts the .xls file to google spreadsheet file that part works but i cant seem to get the function for updating the shared table to work, i cant get the ID of the created file. Would also be nice if a function an be added to the code to to delete the files after they have been converted and the shared table has been updated with them.

```
 function importXLS(){
  var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains ".xls"');
  var destinationFolderId = "ID of folder with .xls file that is being converted each day";
  var existingFileNames = getFilesInFolder(destinationFolderId);
  while(files.hasNext()){
    var xFile = files.next();
    var name = xFile.getName();
    try {
      if (existingFileNames[name] && (name.indexOf('.xls')>-1)) {
        var ID = xFile.getId();
        var xBlob = xFile.getBlob();
        var newFile = { title : name,
                       key : ID,
                       'parents':[{"id": destinationFolderId}]
                      }
        file = Drive.Files.insert(newFile, xBlob, {
          convert: true
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error with file " + name + ": " + error);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Get an object of all file names in the specified folder.
 * @param {string} folderId
 * @returns {Object} files - {filename: true}
 */
function getFilesInFolder(folderId) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var filesIterator = folder.getFiles();
  var files = {};
  while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
    var file = filesIterator.next();
    files[file.getName()] = true;
  }
  return files;
}

function CopyContent() {
var ID = importXLS(ID); 
 var source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(importXLS(ID));//the source needs to be the new file i get eachday


 var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];


var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID of shared table here");
 sheet.copyTo(destination);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Paste Special > Paste values only

The `copypastetype` to use is `PASTE_VALUES`

Example from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination-copypastetype-transposed

```
// The code below copies only the values of the first 5 columns over to the 6th column.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
sheet.getRange("A:E").copyTo(sheet.getRange("F1"), spreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);
```

Comment: Hello, sorry I wasnt very clear. The format by keeping the format i meant that the excel files I get contain the correct formatting (the needed cells are colored accordingly) and i want to import the whole excel table as it is into the google spreadsheet. And everytime the script runs for a new excel table it should change the spreadsheets values and formatting.

Comment: Or alternatively I have a script to convert the excel files into google spreadsheet files. I want to copy the whole spreadsheet from the converted file and replace them into the table i need to update. That needs to be done everyday. The script being updated must be the same every time, I cant make a different one. But the files that i will be getting the updated info from will always be different uploads just with the same name.

Comment: @jjmarulata Please edit your question to add all the relevant details to it.